# Hive INSERT to string column rounds the numeric string

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_ids (id STRING)
```

When I insert a large numeric value to this string column, it gets rounded:

```
INSERT INTO test_ids SELECT "12345678901234567890"
```

When checking the stored value, it comes back like this:

```
12345678901234567000
```

Notes: this is on a Hortonworks deployment of hive 3.1.0

Comment: is there a reason for not choosing `bigint` datatype for the column?

Comment: It is obvious but I explain anyways: These numbers I'm storing are very large and do not fit in BIGINT either. That's why I'm trying to use string. These are IDs and I receive them like this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized this rounding is not done in hive, but in Zeppelin UI where I run my SELECT query which returns rounded result. There is an open bug for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1434

It is only rounding when showing on UI, so underlying data is correct.